# Traefik ACME add subnet or IP to certificate generation for x509 verification

Tags: ssl-certificate, reverse-proxy, traefik, lets-encrypt, acme

When I generate a certificate for SSL/TLS encryption I would like to add extra IP addresses.

When setting up a reverse proxy to a host outside the standard docker networks, certificate verification fails with the following message:

```
msg="'500 Internal Server Error' caused by: tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate is valid for 127.0.0.1, ::1, 192.168.2.10, not 192.168.1.2"
```

Is there a way to add 192.168.1.0/24 (or any other cidr) to the certificate?

Note, I can circumvent this issue by adding insecureSkipVerify:

```
      --serversTransport.insecureSkipVerify=true
```

However I would like to do it the proper way.